# VBA - Multiple sheets CSV export in the same folder

Tags: vba, csv, export-to-csv

I have a VBA macro which allows me to export in CSV (using the comma as separator) some sheets of my excel file, in this case, first 7 sheets. I have following problems:

1. The code allows to export first 1 - n sheets, but I would like to put the code to select sheets by name. In this case I could also export the sheet 1, called "MILANO" and the sheet 5, called "ROME".
2. I cannot find the way to save the CSV files automatically in the same folder of the source excel file. I used ActiveWorkbook.Path or ThisWorkbook.Path, but I guess I wrong something
3. I cannot export only rows of each sheet not-empty as in the CSV I see hundreds of rows with ,,,,,,,,,

Here the macro:

```
Sub CreateCSV()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'-----------------------------
'DECLARE AND SET VARIABLES
Dim wb1 As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet
Dim wbname As String, I As Integer
Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
'-----------------------------
'CYCLE THROUGH SHEETS AND MATCH UPLOAD
For I = 1 To 7
wbname = Worksheets(I).Name

'-----------------------------
'COPY SHEET INTO NEW CSV FILE
    Worksheets(I).Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & wbname &      "/.csv", _
    FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    wb1.Activate
Next I
'-----------------------------
'CLEANUP
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this for your point 2

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=wb1.Path & "\" & wbname & ".csv", _

Comment: Sorry, but I tried already but it gives error :(. Any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

With regards to accessing you sheets by name you can do this,

```
set sh = ThisWorkBook.Sheets("MILANO")
```

but since you would want to loop through your sheets anyway, you need have an array with you sheet names like so,

```
Dim mySheets as Variant
Dim sh as WorkSheet
Dim I as Long

mySheets=Array("MILANO" , "MONACO", "ROME")

For I = 0 to UBound(mySheets)
    Set sh = ThisWorkBook.Sheets(mySheets(I))
    sh.SaveAs FileName:=ThisWorkBook.Path & "\" & mySheets(I), _
              FileFormat:=xlCSV
Next I
```

So you need to use the WorkSheet.SaveAs and not the WorkBook.SaveAs

as far as "I cannot export only rows of each sheet not-empty as in the CSV I see hundreds of rows with ,,,,,,,,," Perhaps you need to cleanup the Worksheet first

Comment: Thank you gr8tech! Sorry, I am not so much familiar with VBA, could you post me the entire code including your contribution? :)

Comment: I applied this code: `Sub CreateCSV()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'-----------------------------
Dim mySheets As Variant
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim I As Long

mySheets = Array("DASHBOARD", "PRODUCTS", "FACILITIES")

For I = 0 To UBound(mySheets)
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(mySheets(I))
h & "\" & mySheets(I), _
              FileFormat:=xlCSV
Next I

'-----------------------------
'CLEANUP
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub` but I get error on saveas